# How to run mongorestore command from mongodb in cmd on windows7?

Tags: mongodb

I have mongo DB installed in the following path `c:/mongodb/bin`. I have configured my environment variable PATH in advanced settings. I have run mongod, it is running fine.But when I run `mongorestore dump` from the following path
  `c:/dump (This contains the BSON files)` I m getting the error.

when I run this command

`C:\>mongorestore c:/dump`

get following error

`2015-05-28T12:59:20.189+0530    Failed: error connecting to db server: no
  reachable servers`.

Please, give me the solution for how to run this command and restore the files from dump folder?